# Curls vs fsockopen - what's faster

Tags: php, performance, curl, fsockopen

what's faster, CURL or fsockopen (POST request)?
Maybe there is something faster than both of them?

If not, then if I'll reuse curl's handle, will it be equal to reusing connection? (So connecting to server is skipped, only writing and receiving response)

Comment: You are comparing two different things.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make a significant difference, maybe `fsockopen` to be slightly faster, but cURL has so much easy to use features that the trade-off for a 0.00000001 microsecond like speedup is.. acceptable in any case.

Comment: So did you benchmark and come to the conclusion that it is 0.0000001 difference? Or can you actually provide the numbers that you don't think is "significant" ? Also, CPU/Memory/Exectuion etc costs, you got testresults from those?